# Python code trying to save excel data into database - error escaping special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, escaping

Can someone please help me? I'm trying to read data from an excel file, save everything into a database file, then query the database and print all the name attributes. I'm using Python with sqlite3.

There are special caracters in the strings in my excel, so I'm trying to escape them. I don't need the special characters. I looked for the solution on google, but couldn't find out how to do it. I'm still a beginner at python and databases.

I got this error message:

[image]

When I saved all the data without the "re.escape", I got this error message:

OperationalError: near "6": syntax error

This is all the content of hamburgers.xlsx:
[image: Excel file]

```
import re
import openpyxl
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

wb_ins = openpyxl.load_workbook("hamburgers.xlsx")
sheet_ins = wb_ins['Hamburger']
try:
    connection = sqlite3.connect("hamburger.db")
    print("hamburger.db created")    
except Error as e:
    print(e)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hamburger")

sql = """CREATE TABLE hamburger (
    last_found Date,
    name char(10),
    stored number(4),
    hamb_id char(30) PRIMARY KEY);"""

cursor.execute(sql)

for row in sheet_ins.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=4):
    last_found = row[0].value
    name = re.escape(row[1].value)
    stored = row[2].value
    hamb_id= re.escape(row[3].value)

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO hamburger VALUES('{lf}', '{n}', '{s}', '{hid}');".format(lf=last_found, n=name, s=stored, hid=hamb_id))

cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM hamburger")
name = cursor.fetchall()
print(name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `re.escape` and don't use string formatting with SQL queries, which is a (very) bad practice anyway since it exposes your code to SQL injections.

For example, if someone were to provide you an Excel sheet that contained a row where `hamb_id` is `fake_hamb_id'); DROP TABLE hamburger; --` then your code would execute the query:

```
INSERT INTO hamburger VALUES('1', '2', '3', 'fake_hamb_id'); DROP TABLE hamburger; --');
```

Which in this case "just" deletes hamburgers from a DB, but it could just as easily do

```
SELECT * FROM your_users_table;
```

**Instead**, use a parametrized query:

```
last_found = row[0].value
name = row[1].value
stored = row[2].value
hamb_id= row[3].value

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO hamburger VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);",
               (last_found, name, stored, hamb_id))
```

Comment: Thank you @DeepSpace, it works :) After the query, I got this: ("big_mac\\ 45'' '",)        instead of the original name value from excel: big_mac\ 45'' '. Why is it different? What should I do if I wanted to get exactly the same? (if I decided to keep all the special characters as well)

Comment: @Tio Becuase the `'\'` has to be escaped when printing the value. The actual value in the DB is `big_mac\ 45'' '`

Comment: than it's perfect :) thank you for the explanation, @DeepSpace! I'm stuck at a different problem now... Do you know if this should work? 1: open database (connection), 2: create cursor, 3: create 1st table, 4: close cursor, 5: close connection, 6: open same database again (connection), 2: create cursor, 3: create 2nd table, 4: close cursor, 5: close connection? It gives me an error: database is locked. How can it be locked if I closed it after I put the first database's data in it?